# mouse_event block on explorer.exe

Tags: c++, windows, sendinput

Am developing a remote access application, like teamviewer. Where i will be sending mouse events from client to server (executed at server using mouse_event() function). But for some reason mouse events are blocked, server is able to receive them and post them to OS using mouse_event() api, but there is no result.

Is there any tool to check, why OS has not executed these mouse events.

Note: Key board events work well and good. And i tried SendInput() api also.

Am developing the application using C++ on windows.

Please let me know your suggestions on the same.

Thanks in advance,
Paul.